# Why the output of this is number instead of items in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My intention is is to get an array of arrays. i.e [['item','C']]. I'm unable to figure out why the below code always produces [2]  ? Could someone please help?

```js
function arrayOfArrays() 
{
 return [].concat([].push('item','C'))
}

console.log(arrayOfArrays());
```

console.log(arrayOfArrays());

Comment: That is because then return value of [`.push(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) is a number (the length of the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns:

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

Whereas, [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns:

> A new Array instance.

Try this instead:

```js
console.log( [[].concat('item','C')] );
// OR
console.log( [ ['item','C'] ] );
```